# Close stats "closed" time span doesn't match selected time span

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, moderator-tools, review-stats

The interpretation of which closed questions are included in the close stats is reasonably fuzzy. It could be limited by either:

- The time a question was closed, *or*
- The time a closed question was asked.

Currently it is the former. I think it should be the latter.

[For example](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=today) (the issue isn't limited to "Today", I just chose that time span because it's the most illustrative):

[image]

This displays 6 questions asked but 16 closed, with a %266.67 ratio, which isn't meaningful.

I can understand both sides of this. Currently the stats are more reflective of review activity than they are of the progression of question quality on a site over time. I believe the latter is more interesting and useful, at least for smaller sites, especially beta sites where clean-up and site quality improvements are a focus.

**Alternatively:** If it is to remain as is I think it would be clearer to at least remove any info about questions *asked* from this page and limit it *only* to things closed within the given time span.

I've hesitantly given this [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), feel free to change the tag (and actually if it's going to get a [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) I'd rather it be changed to a feature request).

Comment: I've come upon this confusing percentage many times.  The close percentage is misleading when it does not reflect the actual percentage of the questions asked during that time which were closed.